# Create a mysql database and use normalization

Tags: mysql

I didn't find here any articles close to what I was looking for. I read a few topics but non of them said too much about database and normalization. I learned about normalization from PHP and MySql for Dynamic Web Sites book.

I took an example and, because I don't have a professor to correct me, I need your help to tell me if I am right or wrong.

My example is for a jokes database with 4 tables: 
Users
Pages
Categories(jokes, short films, etc)
Subcategories(blondes, police, lowers, hunters, etc)

This is the result after I applied all three normalization forms :

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `category_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `subcategories` (
    `subcategory_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `subcategory` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`subcategory_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `subcategory` (`subcategory`)
) ;



CREATE TABLE `pages` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `subcategory_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `user_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `content_page` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
    KEY `creation_date` (`date_created`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` ENUM('member','admin', 'superadmin') NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `pass` VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `date_expires` DATE NOT NULL,
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems okey but maybe you make it even better.

- In **users** table instead of  `type` ENUM('member','admin',
  'superadmin') NOT NULL,

add a new table called UserType

- TypeId (Primary Key)
- TypeName

And optimize your User Table
add

1. TypeId
2. ManagerID (with this attribute you can learn who is this user's admin or superadmin)

last step
If you have a lot of subcategories separete the tables. If you do so you can add different attributes to your subcategories(time for shortmovies maybe).

> Adding new tables is not a waste as long as it makes design more
>   clear. But if it is enough, adding more tables makes no sense.